# How to do a dark mode with localStorage in Vue JS + Tailwind CSS

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3, tailwind-css, darkmode

I do a dark mode using Vue3 + Tailwind but when I reload the page or click in some component that reload something my dark mode set's to false and the light mode appears, I don't know how I can storage my data. Here's my code:

```
<div class="relative flex min-h-screen" :class="isDark ? 'dark' : ''">
<button class="px-2 mb-1" @click="isDark = !isDark">
--------------------
<script>
export default {
  setup(){
    let isDark = ref(false)

    return{
      isDark,
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

obs: my dark mode appears because the property 'dark:' from tailwind css in my div's/components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading the Josh answer I just edit some things like the local of the variable, for instance one variable in Vue the variable should be in data().
Soo that's the code:

```
// The button
<button class="px-2 mb-1" @click="toggleDarkMode">

// Click event callback on the dark mode button
methods:{
toggleDarkMode(){
    this.isDark = !this.isDark;
    localStorage.setItem('darkMode', this.isDark);
 }
}

// Your data() function
data(){
    let isDark = localStorage.getItem('darkMode') == 'true'

    return{
      isDark,
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You use the `localStorage` API ([documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage))

An implementation for you would look something like this

```js
// Click event callback on the dark mode button
toggleDarkMode(){
    this.isDark = !this.isDark;
    localStorage.setItem('darkMode', this.isDark);
}

// Your setup() function
setup(){
    let isDark = localStorage.getItem('darkMode') == 'true'

    return{
      isDark,
    }
}
```

Note: Local storage only stores strings so your Boolean value won't be of Boolean type so compare it as string version. Someone may have a way to turn it into a boolean again but this has worked fine for my projects.

Comment: Hey Josh, I try this, but nothing happens, that's what I do: 
```
      <button href="" class="px-2 mb-1" @click="toggleDarkMode()">
in script:
     let isDark = localStorage.getItem('darkMode') == 'true'
-------
methods: {
      toggleDarkMode(){
      this.isDark = !this.isDark;
      localStorage.setItem('darkMode', this.isDark)
      }
    }
```

Comment: Yes, it's wrong? Where I put this function?

Comment: Ok, after some tests my data is saving, but my button don't change my theme now

Comment: Nothing, the same thing occurs, when I click in the button the data is save (soo when I reload the page the theme switch) but when just this occurs, my theme isn't switching when I click in the button, only when I reload the page and the method read my data...

Comment: I try to change some things and when I put "let isDark = localStorage.getItem('darkMode') == 'false'" the toggle don't run, why? abs: my toggleDarkMode function is in methods:{}